# Only changing the mass of the moon, how much can lunar mass increase before the Earth becomes uninhabitable?

Tags: science-based, moons, orbital-mechanics, alternate-earth, tides

Bonus: How much would the increase in lunar mass increase average tides? & which factors would cause the Earth to become uninhabitable?

Comment: Do you want to increase the mass suddenly, or gradually?

Comment: @Alexander Gradually. If reasonable, assume that the Earth initially captured a moon which was more massive than Luna is.

Comment: In that case, Moon can be as big as the Earth - that will make them tidally locked, which might affect the development of life on Earth, but won't make it uninhabitable.

Comment: can you elaborate why do you think that a massive moon would cause Earth to be sterile?

Comment: Other question: does the volume of the moon remain fixed in all situations?

Comment: Will they remain at equillibrium at the same orbital distance?

Comment: Hi, 007, do you mean completely uninhabitable?  Or for humans and existing complex Earth life?  When do you want this to happen, before life existed or tonight or...?

Comment: This question definitely needs clarification.  Key information that is missing includes, but may not be limited to: 1. how this increase in mass is manifest (does the moon just inexplicably increase mass from the inside out? or is it bombarded by bazillions of tiny meteors? or several large ones? or does the method not matter, and only the end result, after the increase is important? etc) 2. how the mass affects the radius of the moon itself (and thus its density) 3. how the mass affects the orbital distances of the Earth and Moon.

Comment: You may also have luck, possibly better luck, asking this on astronomy.SE

Comment: @Dalila 1) & 2) The method is unimportant; the end result is. Assume the Earth initially captured a larger moon of similar density but greater radius.. 3) Assume the moon's speed is increased so as to maintain the same orbital distance.

Comment: @Mikey I mean uninhabitable for a majority of the complex life which currently exists, including humans. Assume a different sized moon was captured at the same orbital distance.

Comment: @Alexander Which mechanism might change the development of life? I suppose gravity and tides might lead to different kinds of animals, but do you mean life might not develop at all?

Comment: @007th Bondsmith Yes. Tides (which were higher early in Earth history) are believed to have played an important role in development of life on Earth.

Comment: @007thBondsmith ...but the method changes the end result ... If the method doesn't matter, then the end result can be whatever you want, since you can just blame the end result on the fact that the method changed.  So if you want to reverse engineer a specific end result, then we need to know what that end result is so we can come up with an explanation for that result.  On the other hand, if you want to find an unknown end result, we need to know the cause (method) to be able to determine it going from that cause forward to the end result.  Either way, we need more info

Comment: @Dalila I'm hoping to have extreme tides and monthly tsunami-like waves from tidal forces on a planet which has lots of life. Initially I wanted 3 moons which caused crazy tides, but astronomy people say that no configuration which allows 3 moons to significantly affect tides is stable. So, I'm switching to one large moon on a very elliptical orbit, and trying to estimate how large I can go and what might be changed by its influence.

Comment: @Alexander Are higher tides believed to have prevented the development of life? Or are higher tides believed to have generated life?

Comment: @007th Bondsmith Generated. [Without the Moon, Would There Be Life on Earth?](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/moon-life-tides/)

Comment: @007thBondsmith  "I'm switching to one large moon on a very elliptical orbit, and trying to estimate how large I can go and what might be changed by its influence."  So we're changing more than just the mass of the existing moon, in it's existing orbit, around existing Earth, we're also talking about changing it's orbit to a much more eliptical one.  So the answer now depends on the details of this new eliptical orbit.  We'd need to know things like how close it will come at it's closest, and how long the total orbit takes.  Once those values are fixed, then we can start playing with the mass

Comment: @Dalila Knowing only vague principles of orbital mechanics, I can't really make an intelligent specification. Arbitrarily, maybe it gets as close as Luna does to Earth, and takes 50 Earth-days to complete an orbit. I suppose I ought to post a separate question . . .

Answer (score 6):

It'd have to be pretty big. And by 'big', I mean instead of the moon orbiting the earth, the earth would become a satellite of the Moon.

And the Moon would be around the size of Jupiter.

I'm taking a guess from the context that the mechanism of uninhabitability that you're thinking about is tidal forces ripping the earth apart, or at least causing sufficient levels of vulcanism to make the formation of life impossible.

Basically, you're thinking about Io.

Io orbits Jupiter only about 10% further out than the Moon orbits the Earth (420,000km vs 385,000km), and because of that it's the most tectonically active thing in the solar system. Certainly no life is likely to ever form there.

HOWEVER, Europa orbits Jupiter at around 660,000km and even though the amount of radiant energy available is miniscule at that distance from the Sun, there's still a lot of hope that life could naturally evolve there. The earth would be more tectonically active at that distance than it is now, but not catastrophically so.

At a more reasonable 1millionkm orbit (where Ganymede sits relative to Jupiter), things would be just fine.

In fact, if you had the Earth orbiting a Jupiter-like gas giant at the same distance from the sun we are currently, then it would be just about as habitable as it is now. You'd have a much more complicated seasonal variation of course because instead of just the axial tilt you'd also have to take into account the effects of passing in front of and behind the gas giant, but other than that, humans would be just fine.

We'd just have MUCH more spectacular sunsets and eclipses.

EDIT: I realized there's another important factor that I didn't address. The other issue to consider is atmosphere retention.

Jupiter's moons all have very thin atmospheres for the same reasons that Mars does. First, they're not massive enough for gravity to do all the work and Second, they don't generate enough of a magnetic field to prevent an atmosphere from being ionized and stripped away by solar wind or (in the case of Jupiter's moons), by the massive magnetosphere of Jupiter itself.

Now, this would be a problem for earth too if it had a really massive neighbor because now you've got the electromagnetic effects on the atmosphere to consider. Earth generates a MUCH stronger magnetic field of its own than any of Jupiter's satellites, which would mitigate the effects somewhat, but not entirely.

Here again proximity is the key factor. If Earth were orbiting Jupiter at the same distance as Io does, not only would you have the tidally created vulcanism to worry about, you'd also have massive magnetic storms. I'm not enough of a physicist to know exactly where the safe limit would be, but there's a range where Earth might be far enough away to avoid the catastrophic volcano problem, but still close enough that the magnetic storms would render the atmosphere unsuitable for life.

On the other hand, you also still have a nice sweet spot the Earth could sit in where its own magnetosphere is strong enough to protect the atmosphere, and everything is copacetic.

You'd probably have some pretty spectactular Aurora Borealis EVERYWHERE, EVERY NIGHT, but that's sort of a win/win in my book.

Comment: The moon's core is dead right? Does that change anything when it gets larger in regards to magnetic fields?

Comment: Well, given OP's response to @Alexander above, I'm reading this as "What would happen if Earth had a MUCH more massive companion" rather than literally "What would happen if the moon we had suddenly got MUCH larger". Thus my response hypothizes naturally occuring bodies of the appropriate mass. Trying to make something the mass of Jupiter out of the same materials as the moon would be... funky... it certainly couldn't form NATURALLY that way.

Comment: Io is already tide-locked. Earth would not be(it takes time) so tidal effects would be orders of magnitude bigger. For Jupiter-sized "moon" just ocean tides would be on order of 10 km.

Comment: It doesn't have to be tidal forces ripping Earth apart, it could just be tidal forces creating, well, tides.  If tides are sufficiently powerful that they erode away any potential landmass, that's generally going to be a big red flag for habitability.  (Notice the OP tagged the question with tides.)  So, don't think how big before it destroys Earth, think, how massive before the tides and other effects destroy its potential biosphere.

Comment: @Cadrac by the time you had a biosphere to worry about, the Earth would be tidally locked by its partner and the ocean tides wouldn't be destructive.

Comment: Would the Earth appear tear drop shaped from space?

Comment: @TrevorD not to the naked eye, no. Tidal forces tend to make planets oblate (oval shaped), not teardrop, but the level of tidal disruption required to have it be a visible deformation is sufficient to exceed the gravitational forces holding the planet together in the first place. TLDR: A planet is always going to be visibly spherical unless it's in the process of being destroyed.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat Many thanks! Your answer is very helpful. Context is: I want occasionally huge tides on a life-rich planet, on the order of thousands of feet of change between high and low tide. Initially I wanted 3 moons, but answers indicated that a stable 4-body system where moons could exert significant influence on the tides would almost certainly not be stable. So, I'm hoping to get huge tides from 1 moon, and leaning toward a very elliptical orbit for the moon to control their frequency.

Comment: @007th Bondsmith I don't know how feasible THOUSANDS of feet of change would be, but this is actually a pretty simple and extremely plausible scenario. If the moons of Jupiter were larger, and warmer, this exact dynamic would be occuring on Europa. So, either put your gas giant much closer to a Sol-like star, or around a much hotter, brighter star. Either works. Then put your lifebearing world as the second or third of four or five orbiting satellites. This is more stable on geologic scale than a really elliptical orbit, and gets you the extreme tides you want like clockwork.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat Neat! And it could work very well. What amount of tidal change might Jupiter cause on a moon smaller than Earth, but larger than Luna? Also, as an aside, I'm perfectly content with a moon that will crash or be flung away, as long as life can have developed and there are years left before either happens.

Comment: @007th Bondsmith quite a lot. Read up on the Gallilean moons, they're a perfect real-life example of what you're talking about. The tricky thing about smaller moons is that when you start getting smaller than the Earth, it starts getting hard for a planet to retain an atmosphere, which is why Mars doesn't have one, so you wouldn't want to get TOO much smaller. Also keep in mind that when you talk about 'tidal forces' orbiting a gas giant, you're not just talking about ocean tides, those forces also cause tidal flexing of the ENTIRE MOON, which leads to lots of volcanos and earthquakes.